Why didn't McQueen, having a great opportunity, escape from the town when Sally invited him for a walk?
McQueen looks towards the exit, contemplating the situation. The wheel clamp is removed. Bessie is not attached. A full tank of gas thanks to Sally. And now McQueen is free. There's nothing stopping him from leaving. So why hasn't he left?

Cars can't walk. She invites him to go for a drive

@Valorum It reminds me of the quote by Sir Hiss in 1973 animated Robin Hood. IIRC: "Snakes can't walk. They just creep".

He considered it (briefly), but Sally had demonstrated that she trusts him and he was loath to break that trust, especially since he's at the beginning of a mutually flirtatious relationship with her, which is something that he's never encountered before.

Once his tank was full, Lightning considered taking off for the open
road. Nothing was stopping him now.
Sally started toward a mountain in the distance. “Hey, Stickers,” she
called. “You comin’ or what?” She drove away, letting Lightning decide
for himself whether to make a run for it.
After hesitating for just a moment, he took off after Sally.
“Mmm-hmm,” Flo said knowingly to Sheriff. “And you thought he was
gonna run.”
CARS: The Junior Novelization

He's also curious as to what she's going to show him, and interested in learning more about her back-story.

“Okay,” Lightning said as he caught up to Sally, “you got me out here. Where are we going?”
“I don’t know.” Sally zipped off.

Other themes include him starting to relax and feel good about himself for the first time in his extremely young and frenetic life, and the realisation that the town (and its inhabitants) may not be what they seem and may have something to teach him. Running away would remove that possibility.

Reluctantly, McQueen goes back to work. This time, he does the paving
job right Over the next few days, McQueen starts to appreciate
Radiator Springs. He likes that the cars take care of each other and
their town. He learns that Radiator Springs was a bustling stop for
travelers before the Interstate was built "It's kind of nice to slow
down every once in a while," McQueen says to himself. McQueen also
learns that Doc was a three-time Piston Cup champion. Then he had a
huge wreck, and everyone in the racing world forgot about him. Doc is
upset that McQueen discovered his secret He tells McQueen to finish
the road and leave.
Disney Pixar: Cars - Story Reader


It was very risky when Sally was giving gasoline to McQueen. He could have changed his mind and run away.

@ЖекаКрутой - He could have, but one of the themes is his growing maturity and lessening impulsivity. He's relaxing into small-town America.

It isn't particularly risky. McQueen had already completed much of the repairs, and it's not like they can't repair the rest of the road without him. And he isn't some kind of dangerous criminal. If he drove away that would have been his loss, not theirs. And Sally sees a change in McQueen's attitude and is giving him a chance to prove it.

The quoted line above was said by Lizzie, who is not a reliable source of information. The point about the horsepower was not made at the exclusion of anyone else in the town, Sally was just saying McQueen was capable of doing the job. Red, Mater, and Sarge should all be perfectly capable, plus they don't have to do it alone. A racecar is not more capable of hauling heavy machinery than a truck. Torque is more important than horsepower when it comes to hauling. Sally doesn't necessarily know the mechanics involved.

Also worth noting that Doc told McQueen to leave Radiator Springs as soon as he saw him, without first requiring him to fix the road. It was only after Sally complained that he changed his mind. If it was so important for McQueen to fix the road first because no one else there could do it, then why would he do that?

It is pretty clear that almost anyone in that town could have finished the job. And if not, then if absolutely necessary they could hire someone to come fix it. My point was simply that calling it "very risky" to give McQueen the opportunity to escape doesn't make sense.

That's the only time I see anyone referencing that and I already said, the context in which Sally said that was saying McQueen could do it (because you might think a racecar wouldn't be able to do it), not that there wasn't anyone else in the town that couldn't do it. And it doesn't make any sense. Why wouldn't any of the actual trucks be able to do a better job of hauling the paving machine than a racecar? Mater is a literal TOW TRUCK. Just horsepower is not enough to do that kind of work, you need torque. No one uses racecars for construction work for a reason.

You're choosing to misinterpret the quote from the movie, and you're claiming there are additional lines in the film that support your point but you haven't produced them.
